# Detecting activity on LVDS line

Tags: high-speed, schottky, low-voltage, lvds

For some test equipment I have an LVDS line running at 100 Mbps. I would like to make an Arduino Due (because I use this for other monitoring in the test) detect activity on the LVDS line.

Using a (bad, slow) scope I can see that the voltage swings at one of the differential inputs on the LVDS receiver is ~100 mV. It is probably higher (it should be according to the LVDS spec) but my scope or probe is probably just not fast enough to catch it.

Can someone suggest a small circuit I can put on either one or both of the differential inputs in order to monitor the activity? It does not need to be production quality, and it's ok if some tuning is required, as it is only for test purposes.

I was thinking about something along the lines of an capacitor (to block common mode DC) followed by a voltage biased high-speed Schottky diode to rectify the signal onto a small capactor from where I could read the voltage using the Arduino. But honestly I have no idea if this would even work...

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is good, but I think that you will have better luck if you put a proper transciever at the end.

A toggling signal will cause a DC voltage at the output. If the recovery time of the 1N4148's is too slow, use Schottky diodes instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQEwv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This would definitely be a good approach I think, but I was hoping for something without the use of a "real" LVDS receiver as I don't have any on hand... ;-)

Comment: That should work.  We used an almost identical approach to generate a turn-on signal for a power supply, when the only input signal available was a clock that could be turned on and off.  We used an LT1720 in place of a true LVDS receiver.

Comment: I hadn't considered using high-speed comparators for this; nice suggestion!

Comment: Just keep in mind that whatever you use for your "receiver" needs to be fast enough to pass the 100 Mbps signal through to the rectifier.  In my application, the clock was a bit less than 1 MHz, so a lot slower than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

A diffpair can do that. even slow devices may suffice (2n3906)

so couple PNPs , collectors to gnd thru 1Kohm  for speed. Put your choice of filtering cap (1,000 pf for 1uS time constant) on one or both collectors.

bias both bases to vdd/2. ac_couple to on or both bases thru 100pf caps.

The common-emitter node gets a couple mA from resistor to +5v; try 1Koh.

ohhhh use 0.1uf bypass on the +5v